# Authentication for separate applications on the same domain

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I've seen questions LIKE this asked, but not this one specifically -- sorry if it's a repeat.

I have two separate applications hosted under the same domain.

```
www.domain.com/site1
www.domain.com/site2
```

I'm trying to use forms authentication in both applications.  The issue that I'm running into is when I log into one application, I get logged out of the other.  Users use both applications simultaneously, so it's causing issues.

I've tried adding separate machineKeys to each application's web.config file, and it's still happening.  I could try using the same machineKey, but the way I understand that is that if they were authenticated in one site, they would be able to log into the other.  Am I misunderstanding that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use different machine keys and set path attribute in web.config system.web/authentication/forms

Comment: Ugh!  Thanks!  All I was overlooking was the path attribute in the forms tag.  Thank you so much.